# how to understand useRefFunction in react hooks？

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When need to use useRefFunction?

How to understand the source code of useRefFunction？

source code：

```
const useRefFunction = <T extends (...args: any) => any>(reFunction: T) => {
  const ref = useRef<any>(null);
  ref.current = reFunction;
  return useCallback((...rest: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
    return ref.current?.(...(rest as any));
  }, []);
};
```

usage demo:

```
  const fieldSetOnChange = useRefFunction((fileValue: any, index: number) => {
    const newValues = [...value];
    newValues[index] = defaultGetValueFromEvent(valuePropName || 'value', fileValue);

    onChange?.(newValues);
    fieldProps?.onChange?.(newValues);
  });
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It returns a memoized function which acts as a proxy for the function you provide as the argument. You would only need this when you need to update/recreate the function, but also retain a stable object identity for use elsewhere (e.g. a `useEffect` dependency array).